# Замена символов по краям каждого слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Новое Я не понимаю, почему звёздочки не меняются на em? Я же сказал найти слово, если оно начинается на * и заканчивается на *

```
echo preg_replace('#\b(?<=\*)(.+)(?=\*)\b#', '<em>$1</em>', 'This text has *two* *italic* bits');
```

Почему выводятся только последние буквы слова, не полностью слово?

```
echo preg_replace('#\*([a-z])+\*#', '<em>$1</em>', 'This *text* is *italic*');
```

Comment: потому что жадный алгоритм у вас и жрет все от первой до последней звезды. сделайте `(.+?)`

Comment: Используйте [`preg_replace('#\*(\p{L}+)\*#u', '<em>$1</em>', 'This *text* is *italic*')`](https://ideone.com/S0QW5a) - у вас захватывающая подмаска захватывает только по одной букве, квантификатор должен быть внутри подмаски.

Comment: (.+?) ничего не меняет

Comment: про \p ничего неизвестно

Comment: `\p{L}` находит любую букву. Вам же надо слова из букв найти, верно? Или нужны только буквы ASCII? [`'#\*([a-z]+)\*#i'`](https://ideone.com/2Lb6td) тогда подойдет.

Comment: где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: @DivMan для этих целей не обязательно задействовать опережающие проверки: `'~\*([^*]+)\*~'`

Comment: @DivMan читайте книгу `Регулярные выражения - Джеффри Фридл`.

Comment: @DivMan  `\p{L} \p{Letter} – символы, считающиеся буквами
\p{M} \p{Mark}   – различные символы, существующие не самостоятельно,
а лишь в сочетании с другими базовыми символами (диакритические
знаки, рамки и т. д.)
\p{Z} \p{Separator} – символы, выполняющие функции разделителей, но
не имеющие собственного визуального представления(разнообразные пробелы и т.д.)
\p{S} \p{Symbol} – различные декоративные элементы и знаки
\p{N} \p{Number} – цифры
\p{P} \p{Punctuation} – знаки препинания
\p{C} \p{Other} – прочие символы (редко используется при работе с обычным текстом)`

Comment: Я не туда + вставил, надо было так #\*([a-z]+)\*#

Comment: См. [*Свойства Unicode-символов*](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php) в справочнике PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае с `\b(?<=\*)(.+)(?=\*)\b` звездочки являются частью предварительных блоков просмотра, т.е. они не становятся частью заменяемой строки. Тут ещё можно добавить то, что `(.+)` — "жадный шаблон", т.е. найдёт все от первой звездочки до последней, `(.+?)` выглядит предпочтительнее, так как найдет текст от первой звездочки до ближайшей справа.

В `#\*([a-z])+\*#` у вас захватывающая подмаска захватывает только по одной букве, квантификатор должен быть внутри подмаски.

Используйте

```
preg_replace('#\*([a-z]+)\*#', '<em>$1</em>', 'This *text* is *italic*');
```

См. [онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/2Lb6td).

Если необходимо добавить поддержку всех букв Юникода:

```
preg_replace('#\*(\p{L}+)\*#u', '<em>$1</em>', 'This *text* is *italic*');
```

где `\p{L}` находит любую букву Юникода.

Если стоит задача найти звездочку, после которой стоит буква, и далее любой текст, завершающийся буквой, после которой стоит звездочка, можно использовать

```
preg_replace('#\*(\p{L}(?:.*?\p{L})?)\*#u', '<em>$1</em>', 'This *text* is *italic*');
```

или

```
preg_replace('#\*(\p{L}(?:[^*]*\p{L})?)\*#u', '<em>$1</em>', 'This *text* is *italic*');
```

Тут `\p{L}(?:[^*]*\p{L})?` найдет букву, после которой опционально следует 0 и более любых символов, отличных от `*`, и вновь любая буква. Т.е. найдутся `*Да, нет*`, 
 а `* \\ *` найдены не будут.

Comment: Я не закончил..  Ваш `\*([^*]+)\*` найдет `*    \\   *`

Comment: Я сделал, что бы текст менялся, если есть одиночные звёздочки, в первой строчке, работает, как надо, а во второй работает неправильно, том должна быть вся строка курсивом, почему она не закурсивилась? https://ideone.com/Mnk3nM

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew не понял, что вы хотели донести? [Мой пример](https://regex101.com/r/G5zcvM/1) && [Ваш пример](https://regex101.com/r/QX1E7z/1) Результат у них одинаковый, а вот скорость моего осталась выше :)

Comment: @Эдуард Скорость есть смысл измерять у эквивалентных шаблонов. Наши — разные.